# I'm having issues with parse errors PHP

Tags: php, html

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mainmenu.php on line 1002

PHP Code lines **993 - 1012**

```html
$hdtcount=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM helpdesk WHERE replied='0'"));
?>

<a href="HelpDeskA.php">
    Answer Tickets<?php
    if($hdtcount>="1"){ echo "<font color=cyan>($hdtcount)</font>"; }
    ?>
</a>
<?php
}
?>

<a href="faqs.php">
    FAQ
</a>


<a href="ipsharing.php">
    IP-Sharing
</a>
```

Comment: So what can't you figure out about that message? Look at lines 1001-1003. What do you think those lines do? There's nothing in the out-of-context block you've posted that makes them meaningful, which means you didn't post sufficient code. See [ask] and [mcve], especially [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

Parse error is syntax error. You’re most likely missing a parenthesis somewhere and we cannot see that with the code you’ve provided.

Is the } inside the open / close of php tags matching an { ?

Also, you can echo html into your php (as you have done partially on the provided code) to make you file look much more clean.